# Selenium Java -> Video player controls are off -> org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: move target out of bounds

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, action

When i am trying to automate video.js player in my app, i am try to mouse hover but it is not working, can someone please help?

My Code:

```
public static void _mouseHover(By by, String eleName) {
        Actions hoverOver = new Actions(DriverManager.getDriver());
        WebElement ele = _performExplicitWait(by, VISIBLE);
        hoverOver.moveToElement(ele).build().perform();
        if (!eleName.isEmpty()) Logger.info("Mouse Hovered - " + eleName);
    }
```

When my video player is in playing mode, controls will get hidden and there is no other controls on the screen so i am not able to hover using above code.

Tried Javascript executor as well, but no luck